# Communicating between docker containers, using docker-compose, .net core api results in SocketException: Connection refused

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to connect to an API in a docker container, from another container.

I can successfully call the API from the host, using this URL http://localhost:8091/api/quote/1234.

When trying to communicate between the containers I use this URL,  http://jobenginequoteservice:80/api/quote/1234. But this causes an error, SocketException: Connection refused.

This is the port config in my docker-compose file

```
jobenginequoteservice:
    image: ***
    ports:  
      - "8091:80"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Service/Quote/JobEngineQuoteService/Dockerfile
```

I am debugging this in visual studio, the api is written in .NET Core. I've checked the docker network and both containers are part of the default one created by compose.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Which port is actually listened to by your application in the container? 8091?

Comment: I believe its listening on 80, my understanding was that when called externally, using  http://localhost:8091/ the compose setup handled routing to port 80.

Comment: Indeed. I misread the question. As far as I can see, all looks as it should.

Comment: Could it be something to do with host headers? In one case, the host header will be "localhost", in the other "jobenginequoteservice". How did you set up the webserver?

Comment: I'm quite new to docker but I was under the impression the host name came from the container, if I inspect the container jobenginequoteservice is setup as a alias, under the network config.

Comment: @Dave did you solve it?